# Translate filter with external dictionary and refresh behaviour

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to extract mapping to external dictionaries. Below is example of one of my translate filter configurations.

```
translate 
{
    destination => "target_field"
    field => "source_field"
    dictionary_path => "mapping.yml"
    exact => true
    refresh_behaviour => "replace"
}
```

When I verify it with

```
\bin\logstash.bat --config.test_and_exit -f .\logstash-6.2.2\logstash-conf\2filters.conf
```

I get error message

```
[ERROR][logstash.filters.translate] Unknown setting 'refresh_behaviour' for translate
```

But this is how documentation shows it should be done - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-filters-translate.html#plugins-filters-translate-refresh_behaviour

I am using logstash-6.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your logstash-filter-translate plugin is an older version.

Try to run
`bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose 'translate'`
and check what version the plugin is, it should be at least 3.1.0.

If it is older, you can use
`bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-translate`
to update the plugin to the latest version.

For offline plugin management, check the documentation [here.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html)

Comment: I just found PR on Github that adds this feature and in fact it is published as 3.1.0. How can I check if this version is compatible with logstash 6.2.2? I'm new to ELK.

Comment: Have you checked the version of the translate plugin that you have? Is it older than 3.1.0? 
Version 3.1.0 should be compatible with Logstash 6.2.2 - it's the one mentioned in the documentation page for the plugin that you've linked.

Comment: Yes, I have 3.0.4. Now I have problem because my machine doesn't have access to Internet. How do I download plugin as zip to install it from disk?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can download it as a zip, but I just successfully created an offline pack by doing the following: ```bin/logstash-plugin prepare-offline-pack --output /tmp/logstash-offline-translate-plugin.3.2.3.zip logstash-filter-translate```. This outputted ```You can install it with this command 'bin/logstash-plugin install file:///tmp/logstash-offline-translate-plugin.3.2.3.zip'```

Comment: You can also check the offline plugin management documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html